# React native: TextInput placeholder not showing up on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, textinput

I have a react-native component which has a TextInput. On android, the placeholder shows up with no problem, however, on IOS, it does not show up. Below I have attached a picture of the problem, as well as the code for the text input.

[IOS TextInput Not showing placeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbzfJ.jpg)

```
<TextInput
        style={{
          backgroundColor:"white",
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#ffffff',
    borderTopColor: '#ffffff',
    borderRightColor: '#ffffff',
    borderLeftColor: '#ffffff',
    padding: 10,
    borderColor: "#ffffff",
    width:"70%",
    position:"absolute",
    top:80,
    borderRadius:10
  }}
        placeholder="Search"
        onChangeText={txtHandler}
        defaultValue={text}
      ></TextInput>
```

Comment: probably related to this
https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/1483

Answer (score 2):

Found out that it shows up, I needed to add this attribute to the TextInput:

```
placeholderTextColor="black"
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Interesting they dont have this in their docs. https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput